# asp net dropdown selectedvalue/selectedindex not updating in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater, dropdown

so i have these dropdownlists that i need to be updated when user changes it's value. the problem is that the value is still the same no matter how much i try. what is the problem?

ASPX:

```
     <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
     <td>
 <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="selectBtn" ToolTip="TRNSLTEdit" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="editOperator" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return PopupEdit(this)">
                            <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Edit-16x16.png" ID="EditVisitor" runat="server" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <div id="modalEdit" class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
                                    <img src="Images/Icons/Sip.png" alt="" />
                                    <%# Eval("FirstName") %> <%# Eval("SurName") %>
                                </p>
                                <br />
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlNodeClass" runat="server" ID="ddlNodeEdit" />
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlTranslatorClass" runat="server" ID="ddlTranslatorEdit" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnNo" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancelClass" OnClientClick="return Cancel(this)">
                                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Cancel-22x22.png" ID="SaveContact" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTSave" CommandName="submitBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnYes" runat="server" CssClass="btnSaveClass">
                                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Check-22x22.png" ID="SaveOperator" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

C# (aspx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RptDataBind();
}

/// <summary>
/// Assigning commands to listing repeater.
/// </summary>
protected void rptList_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var tellusUserId = TellusUser.UserID;
    var operatorId = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "submitBtn":
            var ddlNodeEdit = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlNodeEdit");
            var ddlTranslatorEdit = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlTranslatorEdit");
            ViewState["NodeIndex"] = ddlNodeEdit.SelectedIndex; //Still old value
            ViewState["TranslatorValue"] = ddlTranslatorEdit.SelectedValue; //Still old value
            _administrationSystem.UpdateOperator(tellusUserId, operatorId, TellusUser.UserID, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["NodeIndex"]), Convert.ToInt64(ViewState["TranslatorValue"]), "");
            ViewState["ID"] = operatorId;
            break;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets datasource and databind to aspx page.
/// </summary>
public void RptDataBind()
{
    var userId = TellusUser.UserID;

    _administrationSystem = new Administration();
    _phonesSystem = new Phones();

    var operatorInfo = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId);

    rptList.DataSource = operatorInfo;
    rptList.DataBind();

    if (rptList.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (var count = 0; count < rptList.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            var ddlNodeEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlNodeEdit");
            var ddlTranslatorEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlTranslatorEdit");

            var getNode = _administrationSystem.GetNode(userId, ddlNodeEdit.SelectedIndex + 1); //DataSet from DB
            var getTranslator = _phonesSystem.GetPhoneNumberTranslator(ddlTranslatorEdit.SelectedIndex); //DataSet from DB

            ddlNodeEdit.DataSource = getNode;
            ddlNodeEdit.DataTextField = "NodeName";
            ddlNodeEdit.DataValueField = "ID";

            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataSource = getTranslator;
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataValueField = "ID";

            ddlNodeEdit.DataBind();
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataBind();

            ViewState["NodeIndex"] = ddlNodeEdit.SelectedIndex;
            ViewState["TranslatorValue"] = ddlTranslatorEdit.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

So for some reason. The dropdown list selectedvalue and selectedindex is the same even if i change to another value when debugging, does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You are binding your repeater every time request goes to the server. Don't do that:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        RptDataBind();
    }
}
```

It won't bind the repeater when you postback and your actual selected values will be retained.

Comment: sure this works, but when i update a contact, it's just one user that gets updated, the same user, no matter who i choose. why?

Comment: @Malphai - I am not sure How you are updating the contact, have you debugged the code to see what's happening? That's the best way to solve your problem. If you're stuck let me know.

Comment: the id i get is correct (through my commandargument) but for some reason, it still updates the same contact later when it goes back to rptdatabind?

Comment: @Malphai - I am not getting your question and also it accounts for a different question. Please ask it separately stating where exactly you have problem.